# Are the LibreOffice SVG icon sets available in Ubuntu?

Tags: icons, libreoffice, hdpi, svg

Arch Linux has several sets of SVG icons included with their libreoffice packages. These icons look nice on medium-high DPI screens:

[image: SVG icons on Arch Linux]

On Ubuntu, there is no "Colibre (SVG)" option in the icon style drop-down, and so I am stuck with badly scaled, pixelated icons. I have looked for additional packages to install that might contain the SVG icon themes, but I haven't found any.

[image: Pixelated icons on Ubuntu]

Where can I find the SVG icon packs to install them on my Ubuntu system? LibreOffice is at the same version (6.4.2) on both systems.

Edit: This is Ubuntu 20.04; it was originally installed from an Xubuntu 16.04 disc a few years ago, and has been updated to each release since.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Images for LibreOffice can be found here

```
usr/share/libreoffice/share/config
```

Then you should see archives :

```
images_colibre.zip
etc...
```